# Javascript functions - what could be wrong?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, compiler-construction

I've some experience with compilable languages, but I'm new to Javascript, and it really messes with me. So probably I'm generally doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

A code example (not working):

```
function show_element(element_name){
    document.getElementsByName(element_name)[0].style.display="";
}
function hide_element(element_name){
    document.getElementsByName(element_name)[0].style.display="none";
}
function switch_display(element_to_hide, element_to_show){
    hide_element(element_to_hide);
    show_element(element_to_show);          
}
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,252,98,337" onMouseOver="switch_display("content_navigator_1","content_navigator_2")">
```

And debugging in Firefox gives me the error message while onMouseOver:

```
syntax error: switch_display (
```

Thanks for helping me!

(Secondary questions: Do you also experience problems with Javascript? Is it really a logical language, or just a trial & error language? And is there somewhere a JS compiler, for good sake?)

Comment: It's 2013. Why are you writing JavaScript like it's 1999?

Comment: So how would you write it in 2013? :-)

Comment: @Marcus, nothing wrong with using plain js, just replace the ..byName to ..byId and use id's and not names to target html elements.

Comment: @Marcus jQuery is the solution to everything

Comment: @ajax333221 - jQuery is not the solution to everything.

Comment: @all, about the compiler question: Debugging in Firefox only tells me **where** the error is, but not **what** kind of error it is. It would be great, if a debbugger tells me something like: "The quotation mark " is wrong, you need to change that to '."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific error is here (u have other issues, see bottom of my answer)

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,252,98,337" onMouseOver="switch_display("content_navigator_1","content_navigator_2")">
```

Switch it to

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,252,98,337" onMouseOver="switch_display('content_navigator_1','content_navigator_2')">
```

Let me know if I need to explain why.

One more problem, besides the cause of your error, is u try to call an HTML Element by name, better would be to do it by id, and then use:

```
document.getElementById(element_id).style.display="";
```

Comment: I just want to add: IE 6 understand document.getElementsByName(...)[0] fully as document.getElementById(...). So if you call something like document.getElementsByName(...)[0].innerHTML=""; this works in IE only if you define a id! Very strange behavior, probably this problem exists even in newer versions of IE, I didn't check so far. So you're right, if we anyway need to define an id due to IE, it's better to use only the id. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes around your arguments.  The double quotes are terminating the attribute values.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,252,98,337" onMouseOver="switch_display('content_navigator_1','content_navigator_2')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, try

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,252,98,337" onMouseOver="switch_display('content_navigator_1','content_navigator_2')">
```

or properly escape the inner quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementByName()` returns a list of elements, so you need to use an index:

```
document.getElementByName(element_name)[0].style.display = "none";
```

But, as other people suggested, you should use `getElementById()`

Comment: This isn't the problem at all. The problem is with the `"` characters in the HTML (`onMouseOver="switch_display("`).

Comment: Still I need to thank you, because that was my other error. The online-tutorials are soooo bad. However, now it runs, finally. ;D